# What does SYSENTER do in 64-bit Long mode on Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, system-calls, x86, assembly

There is an x86 instruction [`sysenter`](https://wiki.osdev.org/SYSENTER). This seems to be the Intel fast-system-call method. `SYSENTER` seems to be valid in LONG mode (64-bit) on Intel processors. This seems to have fallen out of favor because of the AMD-provided `syscall`. From my understanding, this instruction is like a `syscall` but the onus is on the user to set it with EIP/ESP, etc.

You can see the [argument list for `sysenter` 32-bit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/13e091b6dd0e78a518a7d8756607d3acb8215768/arch/x86/entry/entry_32.S#L796). With absolute minimal focus to `syscall` and `int 0x80`, what does the `sysenter` instruction do in Linux when the chip is in Long mode? Can it be of any use as-is?

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/SYSENTER#64_bit_mode, https://lwn.net/Articles/604515/

Comment: None of those mention 64-bit code and `sysenter`.

Answer (score 4):

CPU instructions providing access to system calls don’t exist in a vacuum: they’re only useful as determined in the context of the operating system’s ABI. [The 64-bit x86 Linux ABI](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/entry_64.txt) supports the following entry points (detailed on [LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/604515/)):

- `SYSCALL` from 64-bit code;
- interrupt 0x80 from 32- and 64-bit code;
- `SYSENTER` from 32-bit code.

(The extra 32-bit `SYSCALL` documented in the kernel is potentially confusing — it’s the x32 system call interface, which uses 32-bit pointers from 64-bit code.)

From userspace, things are simpler still:

- `i386` code (32-bit code with 32-bit pointers) should use `__kernel_vsyscall` in the vDSO (this determines which call mechanism to use);
- anything else should use `SYSCALL`.

I haven’t tried issuing a `SYSENTER` from 64-bit code in long mode, but I’m not sure it will do anything useful.